# Can't move a window in Unity (it's stuck)!

Tags: unity, gui, window

Silly question, but I can't move my steam friends list window, the top bar is somehow underneath the main bar of unity at the top.

In Windows you can right-click (or shift-click in Windows 7) and select to 'Move' when a window can be seen directly.

Something similar possible here?

Thanks,

Comment: Also, press and hold the super key for a list of handy shortcuts!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try to press **alt** (keep it pressed) and then click with the mouse on the window and move it.

Also, try **alt + spacebar**, **move** (or **m**), and move it with the arrows.

Any result?

Answer (score 2):

## Use the CTRL + ALT + Numpad [1-9] keyboard shortcut

You may also want to try using the **CTRL + ALT + Numpad [1-9]** key combination. It resizes and moves the currently active window into a part of the screen that corresponds to that number.

- Numpad keys **1**, **3**, **7** and **9** make the window occupy 1/4th of the screen and move it to the corresponding corner
- Numpad keys **2**, **4**, **6** and **8** make the window occupy half of the screen and move it to the corresponding half of the screen.
- Numpad key **5** resizes the window to full size and non-maximised, or toggles maximise if the window is already at that size.

### Why this may be useful

I found that sometimes windows seem move "off-screen" when you try to restore them from the taskbar. In this case you sometimes you can't even see the window that moved off-screen, so you can't use the Alt + Drag method as you have no part of the window to grab onto (please correct me if this is inaccurate information and I was wrong). This method places the window somewhere you can see, so you can now resize and move the window again.