# Can't move windows around

Tags: unity

Ubuntu Desktop (on a laptop)
14.04 LTS
x64
6 GB ram
intel i5
500 gb disk

After fixing my broken desktop session where the "launcher" dissapeared ([No launcher or menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286853/no-launcher-or-menu)) I can no longer move windows around.  If I have several terminals up, I can't grab the title bars and move them.  It would seem I can resize them but I can't move them.

I can maximize, minimize and close but they're stuck where they are for the most part.  Sometimes I like to manually tile my windows.

This doesn't work (alt+spacebar (move)):  [Can't move a window in Unity (it's stuck)!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/358578/cant-move-a-window-in-unity-its-stuck)

I have another session that I created because the first one was broken and used that for MONTHS until I finally found that launcher fix.  Now I'm back in but this piece is broken, a bit irritating but I can live with it for now...it's better than nothing!

Anyone else have this issue?

Comment: I have this issue to. Where you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: Still debugging it. Seems user-account related: with Guest session login moving windows around works well.

Comment: This has been a while but yes - turns out it's a Unity issue.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/476980/i-cant-move-any-windows-in-unity  and they specifically say:  "There's a checkbox setting in CompizConfig Settings Manager (CCSM), under the Window Management category, called "Move Window". It was unchecked. Checking it seems to have unlocked everything, allowing me to move my windows"